# jenkins.build.log() is rejected with jenkins: build.log: forbidden

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I write a node.js app that interacts with jenkins and uses [node-jenkins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jenkins).

It works well with APIs like `jenkins.job.get` and `jenkins.build.get`, but when I try to use `jenkins.build.log`or `jenkins.build.logStream`, it fails with an error: `jenkins: build.log: forbidden`.

The returned message in the failure response is `No valid crumb was included in the request`.

What am I doing wrong?

(I opened [an issue](https://github.com/silas/node-jenkins/issues/42) for this as well)

We use Jenkins version 2.7.1.

**Edit**: If I send the same URL (`/job‌​/MY_JOB/my_build_num‌​ber/logText/progress‌​iveText`) with `http.request` using `POST` I get the same response, but if I use `GET` I get the log properly.

Comment: can you attempt to log somehow the headers that are sent to Jenkins ?

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix Yes, the returned error contains them:
`request.req2: {"auth":"my_username:my_pass","hostname":"my_host","port":"my_port","path":"/job/MY_JOB/my_build_number/logText/progressiveText","method":"POST","headers":{"referer":"http://my_username:my_pass@my_host:my_port/","content-type":"application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8","content-length":0}}`

Comment: from what I have seen this kind of error message occurs when certain headers are not sent along with the request or csrf checking fails or proxy in between ,which returns and 401, if you look at GitHub repository of Jenkins it was patched for versions >2. Recheck the configuration on client and Jenkins there might be something you have missed . You will have better luck finding a solution in GitHub repo of the client.

Answer (score 0):

After `node-jenkins` author, [silas](https://github.com/silas) answered [my issue](https://github.com/silas/node-jenkins/issues/42#issuecomment-294060143), I found the problem. I simply needed to add `crumbIssuer: true` to my `jenkins` initialization code:

```
jenkins = require('jenkins')({ baseUrl: 'http://admin:admin@localhost:8080', crumbIssuer: true });
```